# Save selected data to database

Tags: vb.net

I have a form in vb.net with textbox as ID,Age, Sex ,HB, BG and 2 tables in database access . 
In table 1, there are ID,Age,Sex, HB.

In table2 there are ID,Age,Sex and BG.

When i save data with one button and enter value in ID,Age,Sex and HB , the data will be saved in Table1.

And when I enter value in ID,Age,Sex and BG, the data should be saved in Table2.

Finally when i enter value in ID,Age,Sex,HB,BG, the data should be saved in both tables.
So how can i do that?

Comment: step 0 - read up on normalization.  there is no reason to repeat Age and Sex in 2 different tables.  what happens when BG changes?  will you update 2 tables?

Comment: Actually both the tables are in register form.

Comment: There is one register as Hb Report Register.I have to make one register as ID,Age,Sex and Hb. The another register as BG register. that includes ID,Age,Sex and BG.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out :

```
    If txtBG.Text <> "" And txtHB.Text <> "" Then
        ' Insert in both the tables
    ElseIf txtBG.Text <> "" And txtHB.Text = "" Then
        ' Insert in table1
    ElseIf txtHB.Text <> "" And txtBG.Text = "" Then
        ' Insert in table2
    End If
```

Hope this helps you.